# How do I interact with closed-source Solana programs with no public IDL?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, program, idl

How do I interact with a program that has no open source and no Anchor program IDL. I need to get types, accounts and instructions for this program: https://solscan.io/account/F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf

Is there any way to get what I need?

Comment: i don't think u can interact

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whether the program is written in Native Rust or Anchor, your course of action may vary.

A few options:

- Use Metaplex Shank: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/shank
- If there's no public IDLs, and it's no open-source, you'll need to reverse engineer an IDL via client-side JS

If it's written in native:

- Native to Anchor (probably not helpful here, still included): https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor

If there's no IDL available, and you can't find any open-source code, your only real option is to reverse engineer the program. One way to do this is to reference the explorer to find exposed instructions, and attempt to call them through your own client side JS. Doing this requires a bit of sleuthing + trial and error.

This article from OtterSec might help with this: https://osec.io/blog/2022-08-27-reverse-engineering-solana

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joeys answer: Not quite sure how much it will help you, but you can decompile solana programs like so if you have the .so file. Not sure if that will also work when you download it from the chain directly. But maybe interesting nevertheless.

```
brew install binutils
llvm-objdump \
--demangle \
--print-imm-hex \
-g --full-leading-addr \
--debug-vars --section-headers \
--symbolize-operands \
--source --disassemble sol_hunter.so
```

[image]